# postgresqlのpg_database_owner等の定義済みロールは特別なものですか？

Tags: postgresql

postgresqlには`pg_database_owner`等の定義済みロールがあります。
https://www.postgresql.jp/document/14/html/predefined-roles.html

これらの定義済みロールについて勉強しているのですが、公式の説明がドキュメントの数行のテキストしか見当たりません。
(暗黙的に現在の～ とかあるけど、現在の定義は？ とか)
ですので、文章ではなく実際の定義文を読んで理解しようと考えましたが、どこに定義されているのか分かりません。

定義済みロールはc言語などpostgresqlのエンジンの中に直接定義された特別なロールで、同等のロールをユーザーが定義する事は不可能ですか？
それとも、`CREATE ROLE～～` というコマンドを実行すれば定義済みロールと全く同じロールを作る事が可能ですか？